# Convert date string with days as a float to datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

I have a array of floats in Python that look like:

```
[20010101.0, 20010101.25, 20010101.5, 20010101.75, 20020102.0, ...]
```

How can I convert this to a `datetime` object instance taking the decimals properly into account, so that I do not lose the information of the hours?

```
dat1 = dt.datetime.strptime(str(20010101.25), "%Y%m%d.%f")
print(dat1.date())
print(dat1.hour)
```

gives, logically:

```
2001-01-01
0
```

but I would like it to give:

```
2001-01-01
6
```

Comment: Is it always `.0`, `.25`, `.5` and `.75`?

Comment: Yes, I mean, I could of course preprocess it myself, but I mostly wondering if I can do this with the stringformat in the function.

Comment: How come .25 become 6 ?

Comment: Because there are 24  hours in a day and 6/24 = 0.25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just convert the hour before passing it to strptime as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = [20010101.0, 20010101.25, 20010101.5, 20010101.75, 20020102.0]

for a_date in dates:
    date, hour = divmod(a_date, 1)
    print datetime.strptime('{} {}'.format(int(date), int(24.0 * hour)), "%Y%m%d %H")
```

Giving you:

```
2001-01-01 00:00:00
2001-01-01 06:00:00
2001-01-01 12:00:00
2001-01-01 18:00:00
2002-01-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: This seems like an elegant solution, given that what I want to do is not directly possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way,

There are only 4 format specifiers for hours

> %H    Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.   07
>
> %-H   Hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number. (Platform specific)   7
>
> %I    Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.   07
>
> %-I   Hour (12-hour clock) as a decimal number. (Platform specific)   7

You will have to parse hours part yourself and add to `datetime` object.

Comment: Any chance of knowing why the down vote? Or is there a way that strptime will automatically convert hours given in percentage of 24 to actual hours?

Comment: Agree, I think it's a responsible answer, add it back

Answer (score -1):

I think it's better to process origin data before put it into datetime module, like below:

```
day, hour = str(20010101.25).split('.')
new_date = day + str(int(float(hour)*24/100))
print datetime.datetime.strptime(new_date, "%Y%m%d%H")
```